# Redis Pipe Breaking Down on Linux

Tags: python, bash, redis, celery, message-queue

I am using the celery library with Python for parallel processing of some fairly big data sets. But the daily cronjob I run, breaks every two or three days, giving the following error.

```
CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ResponseError('MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.',)
```

The redis log looks like

```
7633:M 12 Apr 07:56:28.284 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
7633:M 12 Apr 07:56:28.288 * Background saving started by pid 9530
9530:C 12 Apr 07:56:28.372 * DB saved on disk
9530:C 12 Apr 07:56:28.373 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
7633:M 12 Apr 07:56:28.388 * Background saving terminated with success
7633:M 12 Apr 08:01:29.065 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
7633:M 12 Apr 08:01:29.065 # Can't save in background: fork: Cannot allocate memory
7633:M 12 Apr 08:01:35.083 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
7633:M 12 Apr 08:01:35.088 * Background saving started by pid 9998
9998:C 12 Apr 08:01:35.099 * DB saved on disk
9998:C 12 Apr 08:01:35.101 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
7633:M 12 Apr 08:01:35.188 * Background saving terminated with success
```

The relevant system configurations are

- Python 3.6
- Celery 4.2.1
- Redis Server and CLI 4.0.9
- Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)

The funny thing is, the exact same configuration and system is running fine on another (development) server, and also another one running Ubuntu 16.04. But the production one is failing. Note that I am not a big expert on celery and redis, just got the code working after lots of googling and following some tutorials. So please try to keep the troubleshooting steps in relatively elementary terms. Also, when I ping the redis-cli on the shell, I get a pong in return, which suggests the server is running.

Comment: Hey, can you also share the tail of your Redis log. What is that telling you before final death?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're running too low on memory, see you log from April 12th: 
"Can't save in background: fork: Cannot allocate memory". It seems like when REDIS is trying to save a snapshot (see [here](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) for additional details) the operation fails, until the point when it cannot recover. 
Assuming you're using large data-sets, possible solutions may be:

1. If possible, add expiration time for data you no longer need. More details [here](https://redis.io/commands/ttl).
2. Increase your memory-size, though if you constantly add data, it may explode at some point.
3. Disable persistence, however, the failure to write the snapshot is likely a by-product of running low on memory. Keep in mind that REDIS may evict certain keys, which may not be a desirable situation in some cases.